# rabbitmq federated exchange for scalability

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmq-federation

Is it possible to use rabbitmq federated exchange for scalability as explained below:

The messages would be published by the application on multiple upstream exchanges working behind a load balancer. These messages published to upstream exchanges would be sent to the federated exchange from where the consumers can consume those messages.

Through this, I expect the publishing application to scale as and when needed by adding the upstream exchanges. Is is realistic and feasible to expect this ?

Also, if above is possible, can spring amqp be configured to connect to these upstream exchanges with spring just knowing the address of load balancer and not the individual upstream exchanges.

Comment: You should ask questions about rabbitmq itself on the rabbitmq-users google group; the RabbitMQ engineers hang out there and only visit here occasionally.